# using a webview to play videos from youtube in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, youtube

I am trying to watch videos in my iphone app using the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
    <body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML,@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiIcqZoQQwg" , 100, 100];

    // Load the html into the webview
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've seen this in a couple examples but still I can't work it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your HTML string isn't properly formed.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    float width = 200.0f;
    float height = 200.0f;

    NSString *youTubeURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiIcqZoQQwg";

    UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView new];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, width, height);

    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString string];
    [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
    [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
    [html appendString:@"body {"];
    [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
    [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
    [html appendString:@"}"];
    [html appendString:@"</style>"];
    [html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
    [html appendFormat:@"<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"", youTubeURL];
    [html appendFormat:@"width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>", width, height];
    [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```

It's worth noting that this code will only work on a device, it won't work in the simulator.

**UPDATE...**

Due to changes made by YouTube, the method above is now incorrect. Use the method below instead.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    float width = 200.0f;
    float height = 200.0f;

    NSString *youTubeToken = @"K95Q0VFyhA8";

    UIWebView *wv = [UIWebView new];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, width, height);

    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString string];
    [html appendString:@"<html>"];
    [html appendString:@"<head>"];
    [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
    [html appendString:@"body {"];
    [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
    [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
    [html appendString:@"margin: 0;"];
    [html appendString:@"}"];
    [html appendString:@"</style>"];
    [html appendString:@"</head>"];
    [html appendString:@"<body>"];
    [html appendFormat:@"<iframe id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"/>", width, height, videoToken];
    [html appendString:@"</body>"];
    [html appendString:@"</html>"];

    [wv loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:wv];

}
```

Comment: it wont work in the simulator? Why is that? doesn't it embed a player inside a webview?

Comment: The UIWebView will get created but the YouTube thumbnail won't be displayed within it and you won;t be able to play the video. This only happens on the device.

Comment: and when I press the button "Done" it seems that it starts my app from the initial screen instead of dismissing the view with the video... do you know whats going on? Is there a method to change the behaviour of the button "Done" ?

Comment: Is your code is not working for Simulator , or we can't play youtube videos in Simulator. I am trying to play in Simulator and geting this error on console. "WebKit discarding exception <NSRangeException> *** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds"

Answer (score 6):

Replace the URL.
Use

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXX
```

instead of

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple one :

```
//get the youtube video token from youtube url //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youTubeToken

 NSString *youTubeToken = @"K95Q0VFyhA8";

//create webview..
    UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView new];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);

//load webview with the load request..
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@",youTubeToken]]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```