# Make custom link in UITextView and run custom method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to make custom link in UITextView with pattern below
and play the video that corresponds to the videoID when link is tapped.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID

Is it possible to run my own process(method) when link starts from "https://" without opening links with safari?

EDIT: i want to make action [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox8lv.jpg)

**SOLUTION:**

So, based on answer by Lion, i made code below to prevent opening url with safari while tapped url is youtube video link.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
NSLog(@"%@",URL);
if ([[URL absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="]){
    NSLog(@"youtubeURL!");
    videoID=[[URL absoluteString] substringFromIndex:32];
    NSLog(@"%@",videoID);

    [self playVideo];
    [self getRelated];
    [self getComment];

    return NO;
}
return URL;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just paste link as `textView` and from attribute inspector check the checkbox for `detection links`. then when you click this link it will open in your default browser.

Now if you don't want to open safari then you can use `webview` to open links.

you can use this delegate to detect click on link,

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

}
```

from this method you can load your webview to run url.

refer this link to know how to play youtube video in `webview` [youtube in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079899/using-a-webview-to-play-videos-from-youtube-in-iphone-app)

hope this will help :)

Comment: My app is YouTube video player app. i just want to play video in my app.Sorry for lack of explanation.

Comment: if you want to just play video then there is no requirement of uitextview. you can play video in webview directly as mentioned in link in answwer.

Comment: No, i already have method to play youtube video(using XCDYouTubeKit). and i want users let play video from description view(uitextview) of current playing video.

Comment: then you can pass this link to this player by detecting click in the textview delegate method which i have mentioned in answer. `URL` parameter is your link on which user have clicked

Comment: Thank You! I finally figured out for way to play video in app with our opening in safari with code blow:`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{
    NSLog(@"%@",URL);
    if ([[URL absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="]){
        NSLog(@"youtubeURL!");
        videoID=[[URL absoluteString] substringFromIndex:32];
        NSLog(@"%@",videoID);
        
        [self playVideo];
        [self getRelated];
        [self getComment];
        
        return NO;
    }
    return URL;
}`